# Creating report of all feature classes in geodatabase using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, feature-class

I am not getting any response from this script and no error displayed at all

I am writing this script to help me display the feature classes in my geodatabase

Here is my script

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"Q:\basemaps\ALTA\FileGeodatabase\AB_IHS_GIS_DATA.gdb"
logfile = open(r"C:\tmp\log.txt ","w")
fcLst = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcLst:
     logfile.write(fc + "\n")
     logfile.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the directory C:\tmp exists. If it does not, your third call will fail.
I normally use unicode and double slashes for my workspaces.

```
u"J:\\restored-20101025\\basemaps\\ALTA\\FileGeodatabase\\GEOBASE_GIS_DATA.gdb"
```

But the big problem is that your logfile.close() is inside your for loop.
That needs to be outside the for loop, or else you will close the logfile after the first featureclass name is written.
You also have a typo in your variable assignment for fcLst.

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = u"J:\\restored-20101025\\basemaps\\ALTA\\FileGeodatabase\\GEOBASE_GIS_DATA.gdb"
if os.path.exists(arcpy.env.workspace):
    if not os.path.isdir(r"C:\tmp"):
        os.mkdir(r"C:\tmp")
    logfile = open(r"C:\tmp\log.txt", "w")
    fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    dsList = arcpy.ListDatasets()
    for fc in fcList:
        logfile.write(fc+"\n")
    for ds in dsList:
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","All",ds)
        for fc in fcList:
            logfile.write(fc+"\n")
    logfile.close() 
else:
    print("Workspace does not exist.")
```

Comment: yes the temp folder does exist and i tried re-writing the code again and now i dont get any error at but it does not display the feature classes

Comment: Just added a code sample

Comment: I got the problem sorted out.

The feature classed were in another subfolder inside the geodatabase.
 my code is right
so what happens is that when i run the script it list the feature classes inside the tmp folder in my c drive as specified

Comment: Sounds like they were in a feature dataset. I modified the script again to deal with those too. The one feature class this script will not get to is a feature class inside a feature type inside a feature dataset, e.g. the feature classes inside a parcel fabric inside a feature dataset.

Comment: Thanks Blord you are right, the script generated the log after i included the path to the feature dataset.

Comment: Hi @Shade, if you found blord-castillo's answer helpful, would you mind "accepting" it?  There's a checkbox beneath the voting buttons.  It's a small thing, but it's part the currency that drives stack exchange.  You might find that people are less willing to help you if you don't participate.

Comment: Hi Blord, I have not been able to find the checkbox you talked about here, I need to vote that you input was helpful to me

Comment: It's a checkmark, not a checkbox. It should be right underneath the down arrow adjacent to where it currently says "4"

Comment: Is it right on this same page?

Comment: Ok, I think I found it but  and the checkmark becomes green i when i clicked ont it.

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: Hi Blord!, I tried runing the posted above just now but its giving me an error on line 6 saying -  dsList=arcpy.ListDataSets()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ListDataSets'

Comment: Fixed. It should be ListDatasets() not ListDataSets()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4411/discussion-between-blord-castillo-and-shade)